# ReactJs - return a sequence of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React class that takes a JSON object array and outputs a set of divs representing keys and values. The thing is, each object in the json has around 60 key value pairs inside; in this example i am rendering the divs for the 19th index for each of the objects:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"
import sample from "./data/sample.json"


class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data
  }
  renderDiv = () => {
    var df4 = df3["Devotions"];
    return df4.map(v => {
      return Object.keys(v).map((host) => {
        return (
          <div class={host}>
            {host} {v[host][19]}
            <div class='space' style={{ borderRadius:'19px',
              transform:`scale(${v[host][19]},${v[host][19]})`,
              opacity:'9%'}} >
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div id="Maps">{this.renderDiv()}</div>;
  }

}

export default Maps
```

what I would like to do is control the rendering, so that the divs for each index appears sequentially on the screen.

```
return Object.keys(v).map((host) => {
        return (
          <div class={host}>
            {host} {v[host][19]}
            <div class='space' style={{ borderRadius:'19px',
              transform:`scale(${v[host][19]},${v[host][19]})`,
              opacity:'9%'}} >
            </div>
          </div>
```

Im not sure if if should just wrap all of sets of divs id like to return in a single div, and just have them connected to a single keyframe, but im not sure if theres a more elegant way to do it.

As always, help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need :

Considering, you have multiple objects, inside each object, there are some data in array, and you want to display all of them in sequence.

```
renderDiv = () => {
    var df4 = df3["Devotions"];
    let updatedArray = [];
    df4.forEach(v => { //<--- no need of map
        Object.keys(v).forEach((hosts) => { //<--- no need of map
            updatedArray = [...updatedArray , 
                            ...v[hosts].map((host) => {
                                return (
                                <div className={host}>
                                    {host} {host}
                                    <div className='space' style={{ borderRadius:'19px',
                                    transform:`scale(${host},${host})`,
                                    opacity:'9%'}} >
                                    </div>
                                </div> )
                            })
                            ]
        })
    })
    return updatedArray;
}
```

Comment: should i just put the code all in the render method?

Comment: @VP9 , inside `renderDiv = () => {`

Comment: i get "instance.render is not a function". Not sure how this might cause it.

Comment: @VP9, replace the whole function with updated one in answer

Comment: same error: TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Comment: finishClassComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17097
  17094 | } else {
  17095 |   {
  17096 |     setIsRendering(true);
> 17097 |     nextChildren = instance.render();
        | ^  17098 | 
  17099 |     if (workInProgress.mode & StrictMode) {
  17100 |       instance.render();

Comment: Update a small change, will you please try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214304/discussion-between-vp9-and-vivek-doshi).